# Javascript - Set array member using variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I need to be able to set the member of an array using a variable, catch being that the variable defines the name of another arrays member. I'm writing in Typescript and ES6.

The code is passed an array as a variable `e` but the name of the `text:` key will be `e.[variable]`.

What is the correct format for setting that variable member?

```
options.push(
    { key: e.Id, text: e.[variable] }
);
```

Comment: remove the dot `.` just use `e[variable]`

Comment: *"The code is passed an array as a variable `e`..."* Doesn't look like it's an array to me. Looks like it's a non-array object.

Comment: @Ryad thats the one, thankyou, was trying all manner of syntax but didn't think to remove the dot.